# How to solve problem with javascript files served from cache?

Tags: javascript, jquery

When server side code is updated (related to JavaScript) the old JavaScript files are served from cache.

I need a solution where the old JavaScript files get updated to their newer versions. Browser cache (related to JavaScript) need to be invalidated once the files on server are updated.

I have got the following solution to this problem.

```
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*10000);

var scriptfile='http://www.whatever.com/myjs.js?rnd='+randnumber;
```

But I need to clear cache only when there is some update on the JavaScript files not on every reload of the page.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Most sites - including Stack Overflow - use a revision number from their version control system for this:

```
var scriptfile='http://www.whatever.com/myjs.js?rnd='+revision_number;
```

whenever the revision changes, the browser gets pointed to a "new" JavaScript file.

You can do this manually as well, by specifying a version number at a central place somewhere, and adding that version number to every script call. When you update a part of the JavaScript, you simply increment the version number.

A third approach would be checking the "last modified" time of the JavaScript files you are including, and building a timestamp from it:

```
var scriptfile='http://www.whatever.com/myjs.js?version=20100803';
```

but that would require server-side scripting and may be too expensive to do on every page request.

Answer (score 7):

Instead of using a random number, use a version number or update timestamp, so it becomes:

```
var script = 'http://mysite.com/the_script.js?2010-08-02';

// or

var script = 'http://mysite.com/the_script.js?v1.20';
```

If you don't want to update this manually, you can either use a `make` script that searches for and replaces a tag with a version number:

```
var script = 'http://mysite.com/the_script.js?{{script_update_date}}';

// have a shell script find and replace the above {{ }} tag with the date or such 
// when deploying to production
```

Or if your version control system uses it (like SVN) you can have it replaced with the revision number so that it is updated when a new script is checked in.

Comment: @Pekka  and Jesse Dhillon- Thanks a lot for your suggestion